# Проблемы с мышкой

Tags: мышь

Когда я нажимаю в любое место мышкой появляется вот эта риска для выделения[image] и она мне просто мешает и никогда не пропадает, например я смотрю видео в ютубе перематываю стрелками а риска опускается и листается вниз до нее.

Comment: у меня такая же мышка и ничего не появляется. Смотри какой софт стоит и убирай ненужное.

Comment: Жми F7 или ищи в настройках «Caret browsing» и отключай

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно нажать F7 что бы выключить "режим активного курсора"

Comment: Включил этот режим, но ничего не изменилось.